# Is it possible to run Flutter ui on runtime? Like .NET LoadFromXaml?

Tags: flutter

In MAUI, you can have UI created during runtime. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/runtime-load

I'm trying to find out if its possible to do something like this in Flutter.